# Oracle query to allow inherited values from parent rows but override parent values with child ones

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Profile Profile_Permission Permission DB structure where profiles can have parent profiles (in a hierarchical structure) 
and the profile/permission many-to-many relationship has a 'value' column where the permission for a particular profile is stored.

The requirements state that if a profile's parent profile has a permission, that child profile inherits that permission, unless the child
 profile specifically overrides that permission with  a different value (usually just true/false) my problem is, I need to write a query 
 that lets me determine what permissions a profile should be granted based on its and its parent's permission values, with the permission 
 values properly being overridden, if applicable.

So far I have

```
select pro.id , pro.name, perm.id, perm.name, pp.permission_value 
from Profile pro 
   join PROFILE_PERMISSION pp on pro.id = pp.profile_id 
   join Permission perm on pp.permission_id = perm.id 
   where pp.profile_id in 
   (select p.Id from profile p start with p.id =6 connect by prior p.parent_id = p.id);
```

My results

```
ID  NAME        ID    NAME                                          PERMISSION_VALUE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6   CS Tier 3   15    Allow issuance of Instore Credits             true
6   CS Tier 3   17    Allow issuance of Coupons                     true
6   CS Tier 3   14    Allow issuance of Cash Credits                true
6   CS Tier 3   2     Allow access to Customer Service Application  true
6   CS Tier 3   1     Allow access to Security Console Application  true
5   CS Tier 2   25    Cash Credit Limit                             25
5   CS Tier 2   17    Allow issuance of Coupons                     false
5   CS Tier 2   2     Allow access to Customer Service Application  false
5   CS Tier 2   15    Allow issuance of Instore Credits             false
4   CS Tier 1   2     Allow access to Customer Service Application  true
4   CS Tier 1   15    Allow issuance of Instore Credits             true
4   CS Tier 1   17    Allow issuance of Coupons                     true
4   CS Tier 1   19    Allow Invoice Line Cancel                     true
4   CS Tier 1   9     Allow Return Initiation                       true
4   CS Tier 1   16    Allow issuance of Club Credits                true
```

Now I need to flatten this out and I have no idea how to do this, or if it is even possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While this is probably possible, if you only need the permissions for the current user, you'll probably be better off just doing it in software, where the solution is trivial.

Comment: probably, however this is supposed to be a service other applications can call when a user logs into their app to determine the user's permissions for that app. Thus performance concerns prompt me to attempt a database solution first.